# c# winform atomic operation

Tags: c#, winforms, atomic

I am novice to **C# programming** and I am handling scenario like this:

I have a Winform in which WndProc method is overridden as:

```
  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == USBNotification.WmDevicechange)
        {
            switch ((int)m.WParam)
            {
                case DEVICE_REMOVE:
                    DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME vol =(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME));

                    Usb_DeviceRemoved(); 
                    break;
                case DEVICE_ADDITION:
                    DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME vol2 = (DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME));

                    Usb_DeviceAdded(); 
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically my form is  getting notification for device addition and removal

In "`Usb_DeviceRemoved()`" ,I check if my concerned device was removed (WMI query)and run some piece of code(basically setting some variable in code that device is no more present ).

Similarly in "`Usb_DeviceAdded()`" , I check if my  concerned device was added(WMI query) and activate that device(some piece of code).

Problem :
Lets say USB device is removed and "`Usb_DeviceRemoved()`" is called ,now in mid of execution of "`Usb_DeviceRemoved()`"  USB device is attached and execution will jump to "Usb_DeviceAdded()".
But i want "`Usb_DeviceRemoved()`" to be executed in one go.

P.S: My winform run in a main thread (STA) and i want everything to be done in same thread

Is there Anyway to run "`Usb_DeviceRemoved()`" and "`Usb_DeviceAdded()`" atomically

Comment: If you don't pump messages in your `Usb_DeviceXXX` methods there should be no handling of additional messages while one is being processed... You either not showing actual code OR imagining a problem.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand. can you please elaborate.

Comment: This is the actual piece of code and it is  working fine , but not in case the case i mentioned (frequent removal and addition of Device)

Comment: `WndProc` is going to be called in MainThread only, so I don't think race condition will happen

Comment: There's no race condition as all of your code is executing sequentially.  The Add message simply gets queued

Comment: [Windows Message Pump - What is it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b44f06fb-fc4a-4fac-87cd-48b2953ea5fa/windows-message-pump-what-is-it?forum=winforms)... I'd recommend to stop in debugger when nested call happens and check out stack. You'll see some call that forces message processing (I think showing modal dialog may be one).

Comment: But i can see addition of USB device ,interrupt execution of "Usb_DeviceRemoved()"  and  Usb_DeviceAdded() starts executing.

Comment: Probably not related: should base.WndProc() be called after your custom handling code--not before?

Comment: @satish2230 is there **any actual** problem with you? Please try it, **feel** it and describe what **actually** goes wrong. As others said, the `WndProc` is executed in one thread only, if you place some **heavy code** in there without triggering any other thread, it can hang your current UI. Your problem may be that when the method `Usb_DeviceRemoved` is currently in process, any other events will have to be enqueued and won't be processed until the `Usb_DeviceRemoved` has been finished.

Comment: @thank you King Kingi just catch the root cause of problem..thank you all for your support